# How to override flask_admin ModelView.get_list to get custom amount of entries

Tags: flask, flask-admin

Now i get all entries in admin when i open page of MyView(ModelView). I want to manage this behaviour and get only, for example, 10 entries. I tried to override ModelView.get_query method in MyView like

```py
def get_query(self):
     return current_app.db.session.query(MyModel).limit(10)
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

When you override `get_query`, you must also override `get_count_query`, for displaying the correct item count in the list view, and `get_one`, which is used when retrieving records for the edit view (references [here](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/7cff9c742d44d42a8d3495c73a6d71381c796396/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py)). It could be that `get_query` and `get_count_query` differs for just one parameter so you can define the method `_query` and then use it like so:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

...

def _query(self, param):
    return db.session.query(param).limit(10)

def get_query(self):
    return self._query(MyModel)

def get_count_query(self):
    return self._query(func.count('*'))

def get_one(self, id_):
    return self.get_query().filter(self.model.id == id_).one()
```